# Where does the method 'where' come from when using the Omniauth-Facebook gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

The code shown below is commonly utilized when integrating the rubygems, Omniauth and Omniauth-Facebook, into a rails app. I need an explanation of this piece of code, line by line.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from_omniauth` is a class method, so any method inside of it that doesn't have an explicit receiver (e.g. `a.b` has an explicit receiver `a`) uses the implicit receiver (`self`) -- and for a class method `self` refers to the class itself. Therefore, `where` is being called on the User class and is defined by the ActiveRecord Query interface. So `where()` could just as easily be written as `User.where()`, but it's idiomatic to leave off explicit receivers that aren't needed (because it makes refactoring the class name easier, etc.).

The argument to `where` is the result of the statement `auth.slice(:provder, :uid)`. Here, `auth` is basically a Hash. (It's actually a [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) object which is a hash with additional functionality.) So `auth.slice` is ultimately calling [Hash#slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) -- which will just return a new Hash containing only the keys/values that were passed in to `slice`, leaving you with `{ provider: "facebook", uid: "THE_UID_HERE" }`. So the overall result is performing `User.where(provider: "facebook", uid: "THE_UID_HERE")`.

Then `first_or_initialize` is called to either find a User object that matches these attributes or initialize a new one (without saving it).

Finally, [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) is called on the resulting object and sets a block-scope method, `user`, equal to the object (and returns the user at the end of the block). Basically, this is in place of creating a local variable `user`. So, then, effectively, it sets all the attributes in the block on the found or initialized User object and then `save!`s the user.